# Recommended Observable type for REST API

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm using Retrofit and OkHttp3, along with RxJava2 for asynchronous.

Is there any reason I should be using something other than Single in the return value of the Retrofit service?

Usually Observables change and the onNext is called again, but in REST, onNext is only called once, when the request is successful.

Comment: If you are not expecting a useful result back other than HTTP response codes (e.g., a `PUT`), you might consider `Completable`.

Comment: I'm using `GET`, `POST`, and `DELETE`. Might use `PUT` for a few things too. Though yes, I do want the results (JSON objects)

Comment: what problem do you want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of Single](http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html):

A Single is something like an Observable, but instead of emitting a series of values — anywhere from none at all to an infinite number — it always either emits one value or an error notification.

This definition exactly matches the case of API calls. The use of Single better documents the intent of API calls.

I have been using Single as the return type of Retrofit API interfaces on several projects and it was very convenient and straightforward to use.

I usually compose the Single with a transformer that converts connection errors and error responses to corresponding domain layer exceptions.

If for some reason you need an Observable instead of a Single, you can still convert it.